# Existence of bounded linear functional following from inequality $\left| \langle x^*, x \rangle \right| \leq C \lVert Ax \rVert$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given that $X, Y$ are real normed spaces, $A:X\to Y$ is a bounded linear operator and $x^*\in X^*$, the following holds:

If there is some $c\geq 0$ such that 
$$ \tag{1} \left| \langle x^*, x \rangle \right| \leq C \lVert Ax \rVert $$ 
for all $x\in X$, then $ x^*\in \operatorname{im}A^*$

The proof I am reading starts with this observation: Assuming (1), there is a bounded linear functional $\psi: \operatorname{im}A \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\psi\circ A = x^* $ (later it is extended to an operator $y^*\in Y^*$).

This observation is not obvious to me, why does $\psi$ exist? Any attempt to construct such an operator failed...

Comment: @JendrikStelzner $\lvert \langle \psi, Ax\rangle\rvert = \lvert\langle x^{\ast},x\rangle\rvert \leqslant C\lVert Ax\rVert$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for every $x \in X$ with $x \in \ker A$ we have $|\langle x^*, x \rangle| \leq C \|Ax\| = 0$ and thus $x \in \ker x^*$. Because $\ker A \subseteq \ker x^*$ there exists a unique linear map $\psi \colon \operatorname{im} A \to \mathbb{R}$ with $x^* = \psi \circ A$ by the universal property of the quotient vector space $X/\ker A \cong \operatorname{im} A$.

As Daniel Fischer has pointed out in the comments we have
$$
 |\langle \psi, Ax \rangle| = |\langle x^*, x \rangle| \leq C\|Ax\|
 \quad\text{for all $x \in X$}
$$
and thus $|\psi(y)| \leq C\|y\|$ for all $y \in \operatorname{im} A$. So $\psi$ is bounded with $\|\psi\| \leq C$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could start by trying to "define" $\psi:A(X)\to\Bbb R$ by $$\psi(Ax)=\langle x,x^*\rangle.$$ The question is whether $\psi$ is well-defined by that formula: You need to verify that if $Ax=Ax'$ then $\langle x,x^*\rangle=\langle x',x^*\rangle$. But this is clear; your given inequality shows that $|\langle x-x',x^*\rangle|=0.$

Comment: Actually I refused to define $\psi$ that way and considered $\inf\limits_{Ax=y} \langle x^*, x\rangle$ instead. But having a second thought on it, I don't see anything wrong about the argumentation. Still, I will accept Jendrik's answer.

Comment: @bpl No problem - his comment appeared while I was typing or I wouldn't have bothered. The two answers are really the same - his is in fancier language; what I said is more or less how you prove that universal property of quotient spaces...